# What's the name for this kind of Android widgets?

Tags: android, widget

In the latest versions of Android the notification area is on the upper left and there is another drop-down menu on the upper right corner of the interface.

What is the name of that are and what's the name for the widgets that are in that area ?

And by name I mean the name of the component as specified by Google guidelines and APIs, not just "widget" .

In other words if I want a new control in that area I need to code a <...> ?

[image]

Comment: I think those are system controls and not widgets. To make any changes there you'll need root or Custom ROM.

Comment: @MorrisonChang so they don't have an official name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Settings.

For reference, see the [source](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/).

Comment: Announced in Jelly Bean: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html